# GET, POST to a rest api

Tags: c#, rest, httprequest

Hi i have a Api that i want to use to collect data from a backend that spits out json i need to get this via C# Application and it's http functionalities. My question is should i use a rest api and setup an async thread that downloads the data and then use the data as i want to from there or should i somehow use something close to a Web Api i have an authentication that is required to exist in a header. This has given me some hedaches because i keep on being split by what to use for what. I mean i need to do a Httprequest with a header. this i later on need to use for posting to another database. but the user of the program should not have to see the data itself. i have two examples that i have done but i don't know with what i should continue? this is my two examples in code...

Example 1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace Plugin
{
    public enum HttpVerb
    {
        GET,
        POST,
        PUT,
        DELETE
    }
    class Api
    {
        private HttpVerb HttpMethod { get; set; }
        public Api()
        {}
        public string startDownload()
        {
            return (Download("sending token")); 
        }

        private string Download(string token)
        {
            string strResponseValue = string.Empty;
            string finnishedOutput = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("Url");
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                request.Method = HttpMethod.ToString();
                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                    strResponseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                return strResponseValue;
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
                if ((int)httpResponse.StatusCode == 401)
                {}
                int errorCodeInt;
                string errorCode;

                errorCodeInt = (int)httpResponse.StatusCode;
                errorCode = errorCodeInt.ToString();
                return errorCode;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example 2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TestAPi
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Api.InitializeClient(""); 
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http.Headers; 
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http; 


namespace TestAPi
{
    public class Api
    {
        private static HttpClient ApiClient { get; set;}
        private string url { get; set;}

        public static void InitializeClient(string token)
        {       
            ApiClient = new HttpClient();
            ApiClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("your url");
            ApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear(); 
            ApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            ApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("Bearer Authentication")); 
        }

        public async Task<Data> LoadData()
        {
            url = ApiClient.BaseAddress.ToString();
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await ApiClient.GetAsync(url))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Data data = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<data>();

                    return data; 
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);

                }
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the LoadData method called in the second request

Comment: that is allittle bit my problem first is that i do not know where to add a proper authentication header in the second example plus i am not getting the data to show it to someone except another local database. So not sure where to call that function?